# Time Complexity Dijkstra

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

If complexity of algorithm is **O(EVlogV)**. Given `E=20000` and `V=1000`. 
How many seconds it will take to execute?

```
20000 * 10000 log 10000 = 800000000
```

what does `800000000` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation is a way of describing how many times a set of operations will be performed. It doesn't relate directly to time on a machine or even instructions required to operate on a machine. So, 800000000 is the number of times a set of operations will be performed when you have a data set of the size E=20000 and V=10000.

Comment: Well, the constant factors are the amount of time each operation takes.

Comment: Splitting hairs: you're mixing up counting operations and timing them. As you stated correctly: O(f(n)) means that there are up to (the largest term) f(n) **sets** of operations (i.e. there is a constant number of operations that is performed f(n) times): two instructions is still O(1), etc.

Comment: 800000000 = number of times a set of operations will be performed
or
800000000= number of operations will be performed

Comment: it's the number of times a set of operations will be performed.